bash - how to remove a local variable (inside a function)
I've read what's listed in Bibliography regarding unset, declare, local and "Shell Functions".
My version of Bash is
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

var='outer'
declare -p var
unset var
declare -p var
function foo {
  echo \""I'm in"\"
  local var='inner'
  declare -p var
  unset var
  declare -p var
}
foo

(the strange quoting around I'm in is there just to preserve syntax highlithing in the following block quote.) This prints
declare -- var="outer"
bash: declare: var: not found
"I'm in"
declare -- var="inner"
declare -- var

There is a difference in unsetting a global variable and unsetting a local variable inside a function. In the former case, the variable is removed. In the latter, the variable stays declared (but unset).
Is there a way to completely remove a local variable inside a function (before the function returns)? That is that the output would be
declare -- var="outer"
bash: declare: var: not found
"I'm in"
declare -- var="inner"
bash: declare: var: not found

That would be useful to test if a variable is non existing inside a function, like in
function foo {
  local var
  while
    declare -p var
  do
    echo "$var"
    ((var++))
    [[ "$var" -eq 4 ]] \
    && unset var
  done
}

This code loops indefinitely, printing

declare -- var="1"
1
declare -- var="2"
2
declare -- var="3"
3
declare -- var

declare -- var="1"
1
declare -- var="2"
2
declare -- var="3"
3
declare -- var
[omissis]

Is there anything wrong in checking if a variable exists using declare -p?
The only mention I found in the Bash reference manual about the difference between unsetting a global variable and a local one is

If a variable at the current local scope is unset, it will remain so (appearing as unset) until it is reset in that scope or until the function returns. (ref. Bash reference manual - sec. "Shell Functions")

where the word appearing is the only clue.
Bibliography

Bash reference manual sec. "4 Shell Builtin Commands"
What does unset do?


See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74410468/1030675 : You can unset it in a function called from the function.

By using \"" and "\", the outer quotes are just being ignored.  It's the same thing as  "I'm in".

A local variable cannot be unset in the function it was declared in. It can be unset in a function called from that function, though.
#! /bin/bash
var='outer'
declare -p var
unset var
declare -p var

function local_unset {
    unset "$1"
}

function foo {
  echo "I'm in"
  local var='inner'
  declare -p var
  local_unset var
  declare -p var
}

foo

Also note that Bash 5 added a new shell option localvar_unset:

If set, calling unset on local variables in previous function scopes marks them so subsequent lookups find them unset until that function returns. This is identical to the behavior of unsetting local variables at the current function scope.


Worth noting that that local_unset doesn't necessarily unset the variable, but peels off one level of localness of the variable (can reveal the local variable in a parent scope for instance).

@StéphaneChazelas You presumably meant  localvar_unset and not local_unset.

If I understand correctly, localvar_unset is useful to harmonize the unsetting of global variables and local variables, in a scenario that's the opposite of the one in the question (where the point was to remove the local variable).

@the_erase, no, I did mean the local_unset function defined here. localvar_unset was added to align with the behaviour of most other shells (except yash and mksh that go even further in that their unset peels one level of localness even when directly called in the scope the variable was declared in).

@StéphaneChazelas sorry, I managed to make confusion out of nothing. Clearly with local_unset you were referring to the function defined here.
